# .csv file strange behaviour on my Mac

Tags: macos, ms-office, csv

I have this .csv file I created and I am in trouble when I open it on my Mac.
Both using excel or a text editor the file has a lot of new lines in the middle of each line, i.e. a single line is split in several ones.

Strange think is that the .csv file is perfectly ok when I open it with the Preview on my Mac or when I open it on a PC

Anybody knows what it's happenig and how I can fix this problem?

Excel:

[image]

Text editor:

[image]

Comment: when exporting as CSV what did you use ?

Comment: the .csv file is generated by a code I wrote in Python